# Google Glass - How to switch between normal talk and voice commands?

Tags: android, google-glass

In the Glass application that I am working on, two users can talk to each other. Once the application starts running, I turn on the speech recognition. When the user says "Talk On," I stop speech recognition, start capturing audio data, and send it to the other end.

I now need a way for the user to turn the talk mode off.

As speech recognizer is not running during raw audio transmission, I cannot listen for "Talk Off" command.

I guess I could process Gestures such Gesture.TAP or Gesture.TWO_TAP to turn talk mode off and switch back to speech recognition.

I am wondering if there is a recommended paradigm for such cases in Glass. Regards.

Comment: A head tilt?  Another idea would be to have a two card scroll view for send and receive and have them swipe forwards and backwards between the two.  The swipe from send to receive would be "talk off"

Comment: Is your speech recognizer still working after updating to XE17? It seems like that broke for those following this thread: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=273#c44

Comment: I am using everything that is up to date. I haven't had any crashes.